# Is this definition already been defined?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I have made a definition of s-convex set for some $s\in(0,1]$. The definition is: For a fixed $s\in(0,1]$, a subset $A\in\mathbb{R}^2$ is called s-convex if $$t^sx+(1-t)^sy\in A$$
for all $x,y\in A$ and $0\leq t\leq 1$. I don't know if this definition has already been defined. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: I'd suggest that you find a better name for the title. The question doesn't seem to be whether s-convexness is well defined (it is), but rather if there is already defined something like that.

Comment: I second @skyking 's comment. Are you aware of the actual meaning of the phrase "well-defined?"

Comment: I really don't know what motivated you to come up this definition!  If you explain it what is going in your mind about this maybe we could help you better! Are jus you  think about a generalization of convexity ?

Comment: @Ashkan -  I just want to generalize the convexity of a set

Answer (score 2):

As the comments say, yes: this $s$-convexity is well-defined. Perhaps you're more interested in knowing how it differs from ordinary convexity.

For $s\neq1$ and nontrivial $t$, an $s$-combination of points $t^sx+(1-t)^sy$ is not an affine combination, i.e. the coefficients don't sum to $1$. So $s$-convexity really requires us to work in a vector space, not just an affine space. Maybe this is obvious, but I wanted to point out the consequence that an affine transformation of an $s$-convex set is not necessarily $s$-convex. On the contrary, if a proper subset $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ is $s$-convex, then I suspect that *no* nontrivial translation of $A$ is $s$-convex. It would be interesting to flesh out that conjecture.

Single points are not $s$-convex. Instead, the $s$-convex hull of a point $x\neq 0$ is the ray $[1,\infty)\cdot x$.

The convex hull of a pair of points is not generally a curve between them. For example, the $\frac12$-convex hull of the points $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is the first quadrant of the plane, $[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$, minus the unit open ball.

The preceding example shows that an $s$-convex set need not be convex, and a convex set need not be $s$-convex. This is somewhat unfortunate; ideally when you set up a range of conditions like "$\alpha$-foo" sets, then you want every $\alpha$-foo set to be $\beta$-foo whenever $\alpha\geq\beta$. Or, when $\alpha\leq\beta$. Especially, if there's already a concept of a "foo set", then the $\alpha$-foo should be either stronger or weaker. It's nice to have *some* relationship.

Note in both the above examples that the $s$-convex hull of a finite set of points is not bounded, and it is not a polygon(al curve) unless you allow points on the line at infinity.

I haven't even thought about how $s$-convex *functions* will work. You'll probably have to be pretty careful while developing them.

Comment: Good.  But I don't  get why you say the convex hull of that two points is not a curve! instead it covers all first quadrant !!
Let $x ,y \in R^n $ , and $s \in (0,1]$ then the set $C = [0,1]x + [0,1]y$ is a s-convex set containing both $x$ and $y$, so it contains the s-convex hull of $\{x,y\}$,  and $C$ obviously is compact, this proves s-convex hull of $ x,y$ is a compact set!

Moreover I think the s-convex hull is indeed a curve connecting $x$ to $y$! isn't it? Am I missing something?

Comment: First of all, do you agree that the $s$-convex hull of a point is a ray? Once you see that, then the $s$-convex hull of two points is also the $s$-convex hull of two rays, which is more-or-less a cone.

Comment: @Ashkan (Sorry, forgot to do an @-reply above.)

Comment: I see, by s-convex hull I meant s-convex combination of that two points, but you mean the smallest s-convex set containing two points !  Right?

Comment: @Ashkan Right! Which is the same as the set of $s$-convex combinations **of** $s$-convex combinations **of** $s$-convex combinations of ... of the two points. When $s=1$, we need only one iteration to generate a convex set from two points. But when $s<1$, a single iteration gives us a set that is not $s$-convex; we need the union of all (finite) iterations to generate a convex set.

Comment: @ Chris Culter-  Thank you very much for your comments. It is informative and very helpful.